# Как выбирается начальное Н в формах личного местоимения (его или него)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему для одной и той же грамматической формы (личного местоимения) выбор начального Н **регламентируется большим количеством частных правил**, при этом со временем эти правила могут меняться или не всегда соблюдаются?

**Каковы причины проблемы** "начального Н" (исторические, фонетические, грамматические и т.д.) и **какова принципиальная ИДЕЯ решения** этой задачи (то есть та идея,  из которой  следуют все предлагаемые нам частные решения)?

К сожалению,  правила нам всегда даются, но очень редко объясняются.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Меня прежде всего интересует, **какой смысл в современном языке имеет начальное Н** и для чего поддерживается правилами избирательность в написании Н  в предложных сочетаниях, в формах со сравнительной степенью наречий и т.д. Это желание следовать **какой-то традиции** или здесь есть **семантический или фонетический подтекст**? Короче говоря, зачем нам это начальное Н, нужное в одних случаях и ненужное в других?

Comment: Какие это "большие количества правил"? Ноги растут от древнерусских предлогов ВЪН, КЪН, СЪН, от которых конечная Н постепенно перешла к местоимению. Затем начальная Н стала писаться не только после этих предлогов, но и после всех остальных. После предлогов, образованных от других частей речи (благодаря, согласно, вопреки и т.д.) начальная Н не пишется. Вот вкратце и все "многочисленные".

Comment: Вы никак пытаетесь вести заочную дискуссию с товарищем Мимоходовым? Нашли с кем дискутировать...

Comment: "Вкратце" тема дается  у Розенталя http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm.   Вот здесь еще "краткий " перечень:  https://otvet.mail.ru/question/38726161. Почему Н не  пишется после предлогов, управляющих  именно Д.п.  (благодаря, согласно, вопреки)? А вот после предлогов, управляющих Р.п., Н пишется, при чем тут падеж? Почему оспаривается Розенталь в части отсутствия Н для  сравнительной степени наречий (лучше его или лучше него)? Почему надо каждый раз что-то "выдумывать от себя", чтобы выбрать факультативный вариант? Вот такие простые проблемы.

Comment: Кем оспаривается? Писать не слишком грамотно – не значит оспаривать. Благодаря, согласно, вопреки не воспринимаются как предлоги, поэтому после них и не пишется. Все не так уж сложно.

Comment: *Ноги растут от древнерусских предлогов ВЪН, КЪН, СЪН* - если бы всё было так просто, то формы предложного падежа не имели бы исторических наращенных форм.

Comment: *Почему оспаривается Розенталь в части отсутствия Н для сравнительной степени наречий (лучше его или лучше него)?* - потому, что если факты противоречат теории, то оспаривается теория, а не факты. Даже у Аванесова, на которого вы даете ссылку  (а он-то специалист именно в орфоэпии), в 37-м параграфе (самая последняя страничка)  есть примечание "следует отметить возможность употребления припредложных форм местоимений после сравнительной степени...". Так задайтесь вопросом, почему Р. оспаривает Аванесова, а не наоборот.

Comment: *Вы никак пытаетесь вести заочную дискуссию* - дискуссия это нормально (в рамках формата ресурса). Ненормально, когда мнение одного автора (даже Розенталя) трактуется как догма - вопреки всем остальным (Еськовой, Аванесову, кажется еще и Валгиной), не менее авторитетным в конкретной области (грамматике и офрфоэпии).

Answer (score 1):

У [Еськовой](https://books.google.ru/books?id=STRqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC&source=bl&ots=aIHh6LR2VB&sig=txO8KerIU1lbUDUvY8-uCjdd89U&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsvqmJrr3UAhUiG5oKHWNuDW8Q6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC&f=false) все подробно изложено, кроме возникновения.

Если кратко, то возникшие изначально как особые формы при служебных предлогах, эти формы постепенно распространились на многие другие случаи. Они давно потеряли сугубо припредложную функцию (там они были чем-то вроде маркера определенности, особенно требуемого при дательном и местном падежах) и стали использоваться как смыслоразличительный элемент.

А что до истории, то там, очевидно, намешана и фонетика, и грамматика, я видел только одну работу на английском, где проводится сколько-нибудь полное исследование, но и оно уровня "в порядке обсуждения".

> Меня прежде всего интересует, какой смысл в современном языке имеет
>   начальное Н и для чего поддерживается правилами избирательность в
>   написании Н в предложных сочетаниях, в формах со сравнительной
>   степенью наречий и т.д.

"Какой смысл?" Некорректный вопрос. Если вы о семантическом отличии припредолжных форм от обычных, то его нет, утратилось.
Ну а если вы ищите смысл в том, что язык устроен так, что в нем есть припредложные формы, а не как-то по-другому, то это просто несерьезно, схоластика какая-то.

Вот кое-что по вопросу о происхождении. 
[http://орфография.орг/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%AD%D0%B2%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD](http://%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F.%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%AD%D0%B2%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD)

Это не аргумент за или против какой-то гипотезы в споре о происхождении Н в припредложных формах, это просто иллюстрация того, что это спор абсолютно далек от закрытия.

Comment: Что такое "маркер определенности"? Артикль?При **местоимениях**? Простите, это фантазии.

Comment: Да нет... Не артикль, хотя некое подобие артикля в русском было, это иыли особые формы указательных местоимений И, О, Я (родовые) и Ы (множественно числа), из них и выросли косвенные падежи местоимений третьего лица. Но это только часть вопроса о происхождении припредложных форм. Я говорил о другом. О смыслоразличительном маркере.